# C# does not inherit the constructor from base class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, constructor

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Constructors and Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617336/constructors-and-inheritance)
>   [Why are constructors not inherited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426484/why-are-constructors-not-inherited)

When define class inherited from base class, I have to redefine all its constructors.
I am wondering why C# does not support inherit from base class's constructors?

Comment: don't think it is done in any other language (like Java). Only default ctor (if any) is called from child class.

Comment: Well because it is a different object. (functions are the same)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Because it makes sense to, if there are no constructors explicitly defined in a child class, allow the constructors from the base class to be copied over. The base class may have variables that you can set with the constructor such as (X, Y, Color) that wouldn't change in the derived class, i.e. the constructor would still be valid.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel for the same reason all other public methods are inherited?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Constructors are not inherited because we wouldn't be able to properly determine how our derived class objects were instantiated. When all derived classes would use parent's constructors implicitly, in my oppinion it would be a problem because if we forgot to redefine constructor, the object might have been initialized incorrectly. If you would like the derived class constructor to do the same as parent class constructor, call it using [base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Also be aware of the fact that the base class constructor (parameterless) is automatically run if you don't call any other base class constructor taking arguments explicitly. So calling `base() is redundant`.

Comment: This is not true. Python uses MRO to determine exactly which constructor to call. You go up the MRO under you find the first one the matches the call signature. There is no gray there. Stating programmers may make mistakes is also a week argument. This is MS treating programmers like kids, and not given the freedom to write good code. Same argument as "Fire is dangerous, you can never use fire"... well there are very good use cases for being able to use fire

Answer (score 7):

The constructor of the derived class implicitly calls the constructor for the base class, or the superclass in Java terminology. In inheritance, all base class constructors are called before the derived class's constructors in the order that the classes appear in the class hierarchy.

Now, if the base class has more than one constructor, then the derived class has to define which one should be called. For example:

```
public class CoOrds
{
    private int x, y;

    public CoOrds()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    public CoOrds(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

//inherits CoOrds:
public class ColorCoOrds : CoOrds
{
    public System.Drawing.Color color;

    public ColorCoOrds() : base ()
    {
        color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }

    public ColorCoOrds(int x, int y) : base (x, y)
    {
        color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

For more information please visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228387(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This is the real winner answer to the original question. Despite being an old post I have no doubt in upvoting your answer. You are the only one who got it right. That's exactly what I was looking for and it works as you described. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Only member variables and member methods can be inherited from one class to derived.