# Can we call a base.base constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor

Given two abstract classes, the parent having a constructor

```
public abstract class MyAbstractBaseClass
{
  public MyAbstractBaseClass(string arg){}
}


public abstract class MyAbstractSubClass:MyAbstractBaseClass
{
  // Properties and Methods
}
```

, can we instantiate a concrete subclass?

```
public class MyConcreteSubClass:MyAbstractSubClass
{
  public MyConcreteSubClass() // Call MyAbstractBaseClass("aStrign")
  {
  }
```

One could create an `Init()` function in the base class, but this would be rather a workaround than a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Constructors are not inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4544382/11683).

`base` for `MyConcreteSubClass` is `MyAbstractSubClass`, and `MyAbstractSubClass` does not have a constructor that accepts a string.

If you want the constructor "inherited", you have to redeclare it:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractSubClass : MyAbstractBaseClass
{
  public MyAbstractSubClass (string arg) : base(arg) {}
  // Properties and Methods
}
```

Then you can call it with `base("hello")` from `MyConcreteSubClass`.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor in the sub class also needs a body:

```
public class MyConcreteSubClass : MyAbstractBaseClass
{
    public MyConcreteSubClass() : base("hello")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyConcreteSubClass : MyAbstractBaseClass
{
  public MyConcreteSubClass():base("hello") {}   
}
```

You have to inherit from your BaseClass to compile it :)