# C# Activator createInstance for extending class

Tags: c#, inheritance, activator, extending, createinstance

I have a base class, which is as follows:

```
public Data()
    {
        id = num++;
        SetVariables();
    }
    //fill every Variable varNames, parseInduction, noise, seperator in Children Classes
    public Data(String line)
    {
        //first declare all variables in sub classes
        if (id == 0)
            throw new NotSupportedException("You are not allowed to use this constructor for creating the first instance!");
        id = num++;
        SetVariables();
        parseLine(line);
    }
```

And i also have a Sub Class extending this Class.

```
class DienstGruppe : Data
{
    protected override void SetVariables(){
        varNames = new String[] {"id", "name"};
        parseInduction = "DienstGruppen = {";
        parseEnd = "};";
        beginOfDataLine = "<";
        endOfDataLine = ">";
        noise = new String[] { "\"" };
    }
}
```

And i try to create an object with the Activator.CreateInstance() Function as follows:

```
Data myData = (Data)Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType(), new object[] { line });
```

Note: this.GetType() is used in a function of Data by the extending class, to get the Type of the current class.

But this causes a problem. Bizzarly i get an error, that the class (in my case DienstGruppe) does not have the constructor. I guess inheritance is not the same in c# as in java. So how can i solve this problem?

It works for "Data" though.

Regards, Dominik

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: What is the type of the variable `line`? You must make sure the argument list and types match.

Comment: i think there is allready an answer from Pavel which should solve it.

line is a String.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answer by Pavel, which is correct about requiring a constructor with the appropriate signature in the child class, it may be worth pointing out why you need to do that.

In C#, constructors are not inherited, as per `Section 1.6.7.1` of the C# Language Specification.

> Unlike other members, instance constructors are not inherited, and a
>   class has no instance constructors other than those actually declared
>   in the class. If no instance constructor is supplied for a class, then
>   an empty one with no parameters is automatically provided.

You seemed to think that inheritance works differently in C# than Java, but in this case Java behaves the same way. See `Section 8.8` in the Java spec.

> Constructor declarations are not members. They are never inherited and
>   therefore are not subject to hiding or overriding.

For more information on possible reasoning behind this decision, see [this StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426484/why-are-constructors-not-inherited)

Answer (score 2):

You should write constructor in DienstGruppe to inherit it from base class like this:

```
public DienstGruppe(String line) : base(line) { }
```

So it requires constructor in child class.