# Constructor on type '' not found

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have two classes like these.

```
public class MyClass
{
    protected readonly int SomeVariable;

    public MyClass(){}

    public MyClass(int someVariable)
    {
        SomeVariable = someVariable;
    }
}

public class MyClass2 : MyClass {}
```

Is there a way to create an instance of the class using Activator.CreateInstance?
I wrote something like this:

```
public class ActivatorTest<TViewModel>
    where TViewModel : MyClass
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var viewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TViewModel), new Object[] {2}) as TViewModel;
    }
}

new ActivatorTest<MyClass2>().Run();
```

But I had an exception Constructor on type 'MyClass2' not found.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're passing arguments to the constructor, but there is no constructor that takes 2 arguments. That's what the error is telling you.

Comment: I've used up my close vote for "offtopic - typo" (which I retracted), but your question seems to be a duplicate of [C# Activator createInstance for extending class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113131/c-sharp-activator-createinstance-for-extending-class).

Comment: Related post - [Constructor on type not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25577601/465053)

Answer (score 5):

on this line

```
var viewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TViewModel), new Object[] {2,3}) as TViewModel;
```

you try to add two int parameters to your ctor here : `new Object[] {2,3}`

And there's no ctor taking two parameters (in the shown code).

Answer (score 3):

There is no constructor on that class that takes two integers as arguments. Add such a constructor or correct the arguments that you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

`MyClass2` only has the default, parameterless constructor. It doesn't inherit the `MyClass(int)` constructor.